# Assume $ 0<x<1 $, show that $(1+x)log^2(1+x)<x^2$

Tags: inequality

Assume $ 0<x<1 $, show that $(1+x)[\log(1+x)]^2<x^2$

I know how to prove the inequality, but I do not use the condition x<1. Is there a simpler proof when $x<1$?

Thank you

Comment: this is a problem from a graduate admission test

Comment: Can you show in an edit how you prove this inequality without using the condition of $x<1$?

Comment: Maybe the problem meant to assume $0\lt|x|\lt1$.

Comment: Of course not. I can assure you that this problem is exactly from an admission test of an elite Chinese graduate school.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proof for all $x>0$.  Use the basic inequality $$\log(1+x) < x$$ for all $x>0$ to get the bound

$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} (1+x)\log^2(1+x) = 2\frac{\log(1+x)+1}{1+x} < 2
$$

for all $x>0$.  Your inequality follows by integrating twice.

Comment: you do not use the condition x<1. I suppose that there's a simpler proof under the condition 0<x<1.